# JPopup key bindings only work 1 time

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I have a static `JPopupMenu` which I create and assign keybindings to using:

```
JMenuItem mItem = new MenuItem( "name" );
mItem.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK ) );
```

This `JPopupMenu` is added to a `JTable` by doing the following:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.add( popupMenu );
```

I also add a `MouseListener` to the `JTable` as well to trigger the popup menu:

```
table.addMouseListener( mListener );
```

I override `mouseReleased( MouseEvent me )` to add the action for displaying the popup menu in the following way:

```
private void checkPopupTrigger( MouseEvent me )
        {
            if ( me.isPopupTrigger() )
            {
                JTable source = (JTable)me.getSource();
                int row = source.rowAtPoint( me.getPoint() );
                int column = source.columnAtPoint( me.getPoint() );

                if (! source.isRowSelected(row))
                    source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

                popupMenu.show( me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY() );
            }

        }
```

The problem I have is that upon first load the shortcut will work fine, it will work without the JPopupMenu open & therefore no need to right click and display the menu if you already know the shortcut you want to press. If I right click and the popup menu gets displayed the shotcut will no longer work once the popupmenu isn't visible.

If I inspect my `JTable` instance ( in Eclipse IDE ) it actually appears that the `JPopupMenu` component gets removed from the table after the following line is called :

```
popupMenu.show( me.getComponent(), me.getX(), me.getY() );
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour? I can't seem to find out what's going on after various different approaches. I have also tried using:

```
table.setComponentPopupMenu(myPopupMenu);
```

But by doing the above, although the menu will display the shortcuts never work unless the popupmenu is visible.

I am running on Windows 8 if that might be of any relevance to the key bindings getting assigned.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I did have this working using a separate `KeyListener` on the `JTable` as well as the `JPopupMenu`, but that meant assigning all the shortcuts twice, once on the popup and again for the separate `KeyListener`. After getting it to work with just the `JPopupMenu` I now hope to be able to find out why the shortcuts only work before ( and during ) the menu being displayed. Even if I don't click on an item in the popup menu the shortcuts will not work after the menu has become hidden.

Thank you.

Comment: doesn't solve the basic problem, but explains the works-first-time: _table.add( popupMenu )_ (BTW, that's wrong, you **never** add a popup anywhere manually) - until first showing, it's a visible part of the container hierarchy (though can't be seen because there's no LayoutManager that would size/locate it) so the binding is active. After that, it was added/removed from some parent (either a window or the layeredPane), so is no longer part of the hierarchy and the binding not processed

Answer (score 3):

> But by doing the above, although the menu will display the shortcuts never work unless the popupmenu is visible.

This is the proper behaviour. Accelerators should only work when a component is visible. So unless the popup is visible the accelerators will not work.

If you want an accelerator to work all the time then you should be using a JMenuBar with JMenus and JMenuItems that contain the accelerators. I like this approach because if provided self documentation for each accelerator.

Or another approach is to manually add [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for all your accelerators. This is the way all the default Actions of JTable are implemented.

Comment: If it's the proper behavior for accelerators, which I thought it was too, can you explain why the shortcuts work before the menu is displayed, but they never work again after it has been displayed. E.g when I load the application and press the shortcut, the action will be triggered, even without the popup menu displayed.

Comment: I would guess you have some kind of bug in your code but you didn't post a SSCCE so I can't guess.

Comment: It was because of a bug, I was adding the JPopupMenu using `jtable.add( jpopupmenu )` as explained in the comments above by kleopatra. Thank you for your help!